# Metro minimizes whenever i click something on my second screen

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

Only just installed windows 8, and so far it's all pretty nice. I run it on my laptop, but whenever i'm at home I hook it up to my second monitor(which then becomes my main display). But for some reason whenever Metro is on my main display and I click on my second screen's "regular" desktop metro minimizes.

I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to do that. For some reason al my shortcut also appear on my main display, behind the metro screen so to say.

I've tried a few different things(moving shortcuts, changing primary display, using the windows+pageUP trick, but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone experienced the same problem, and might you be able to help?

Comment: Mine too, and as far as I can tell this is just the way it is. At work I actually have three screens not two and it does it there as well. As best as I can tell, Metro is really designed with a device in mind, which wouldn't be expected to have more than one screen.

Comment: Right now I have a Metro app open on one screen and the desktop open on the other, so it _is_ possible. Not sure at first glance why yours isn't doing it right now, but there is a way. Somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supposed to do that. The Windows 8 approach to the desktop seems to be to treat it as an activity like a native Metro App. So when you click on the desktop on your secondary monitors, you switch to the desktop activity, hiding the metro menu.

In practice I treat the metro menu like the start menu. If I need an application, I press the start key, type the name of the application I want and press enter. I presume that metro apps like explorer probably have this desktop switching problem. On thing you can do is dock a metro app to the side of a screen, leaving the desktop on the rest of that screen and all others.

In short, metro apps are not multi-monitor friendly. Just use the metro menu for task switching/starting and ignore it for everything else.